# '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' in loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement

I have to find the maximum value in a dictionary called `fav_num`:

```
fav_num = {
        "Ian": 3.14,    
        "Tobiloba": 5,
        "Kaden": 10,
        "Sophie": 18,
        "Aarav": 17,
        "Zach": 6,
        "Ewen": 64,
        "Nirvana": 25,
        "Arjun": 3.14, 
        "Olivia": 7,
}

max = 0
for value in fav_num:
    if fav_num[value] > max:
        max = value
print(max)
```

I have to use a loop, so I set max is equal to 0 and for each value, it compares it with the previous value. It is giving me this error:

```py
'>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Does fav_num[value] not print the corresponding value of the key?

Comment: First of all don't use reserved keywords as variable name, you can rename it to max_. For finding max just use __max(fav_num.values())__  and error in your code is __max=value__ it should be __max=fav_num[value]__

Comment: A dict iterates its keys. Use its `.values()` method to iterate its values. Or take it up a notch and use its `.items()` method to iterate key, value tuples. That way you can display the key and its value at the end.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use different methods to find the key with values in the dict.

The solution I'm offering is simply to compare the greatest value with the greatest value in the value of the Dictionary.

```
fav_num = {
    "Ian": 3.14,    
    "Tobiloba": 5,
    "Kaden": 10,
    "Sophie": 18,
    "Aarav": 17,
    "Zach": 6,
    "Ewen": 64,
    "Nirvana": 25,
    "Arjun": 3.14, 
    "Olivia": 7,
```

---

```
for k, v in fav_num.items():
    if v==max(fav_num.values()):
        print(k)
```

result

```
  Ewen
```

### or

Python can use indexes to keep the Dictionary in order.

It's cumbersome, but there are the following ways .

1. find index

   ```
    max_ = list(fav_num.values()).index(max(fav_num.values()))
   ```

2.Finding Values Using Indexes

```
list(fav_num.keys())[max_]
```

result

```
Ewen
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `max()` function with the `key` parameter to get the key corresponding to the maximum value:

```py
max(fav_num, key=fav_num.get)
```

If you must use a `for` loop, you can keep track of the maximum value and the key corresponding to that value:

```py
result = None
max_value = float('-inf')
for key, value in fav_num.items():
    if value > max_value:
        result = key
        max_value = value
print(result)
```

These output:

```
Ewen
```

Answer (score 1):

### Method 1 : Iterate over items

> You can iterate over each item value pair of dictionary and find the maximum and return it

```
for name, value in fav_num.items():
    if value == max(fav_num.values()):
        print(name, value)
```

### Method 2 : One-Liner

> You can find the maximum in list of values and then get the corresponding key for it

```
list(fav_num.keys())[list(fav_num.values()).index(max(fav_num.values()))]
```

You can visit this page on more info for dictionary functions : [Python Dictionary Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_ref_dictionary.asp)
One-Liner code was inspired from this page : [One liner to get keys from values](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-get-key-from-value-in-dictionary/)